# How to delete a row with JQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a table that displays data for the user. Each row can have 2 functions, one to delete and the other to edit the record. The row itself has an id that I need to reference for both the delete and the edit functions. I am having a difficult time getting this to work correctly.

The last cell on the right is for the delete image. When I click on just the delete icon, I get an alert from the row even though I have the delete cell specified in `not()`.

The last issue I am having is that `$.post` is not passing any POST value. Even if I set it manually, I cannot see it server-side.

Here is my code so far.

```
$('#drafts').find('tr').not(':first-child, td.delete').click( function(){
  alert(this.id);
});

$("td.delete").click(function(){
  var id = this.id;
  $.post('test.php',id, function(){
    $('#'+id).remove();
  },'json');
});

<tr id="5">
  <td>test1</td>
  <td>test2</td>
  <td class="delete">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Use core Javascript function -  http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_table_deleterow.asp

Comment: Check the Firebug console. What does it display ?

Comment: I see the AJAX request but there is no POST value being sent to the server. The GET request however is working

Comment: Try - `$.post('test.php', {"id":id }, function(){})`
That is changing the way that data is sent.

Comment: Joddy, I get this: `Array
(
    [id] => 
)`

Comment: this is Wrong = `var id = this.id;` you need to get `parent` of the `td` and then get its `id`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this code:

```
$("td.delete").click(function(){
  var id = $(this).parents('tr').eq(0).attr('id');
  $.post('test.php', {'id': id}, function(){
    $('#'+id).remove();
  },'json');
});
```

and this one for your **`edit`** action (but I don't know what do you want to do here):

```
$("td.edit").click(function(){
  var id = $(this).parents('tr').eq(0).attr('id');

  // now you have `id` of current row
  // write your code here
});
```

You said that you want the entire row for `edit` action, except the `delete` cell:

```
$("tr td:not(.delete)").click(function(){
  var id = $(this).parents('tr').eq(0).attr('id');
  $.post('test.php', {'id': id}, function(){
    $('#'+id).remove();
  },'json');
});
```

Comment: this is showing me the id server-side now, thank you. What would I need to get the row click with the id for the edit?

Comment: Ok. What to do you want for your `edit` action to happen? Send a request to server? Do some DOM manipulation. Tell me and I can help you :)

Comment: If I could get the id, I'd be happy with that. Basically I need the id for both actions. Well, actually, I would need a way to differentiate between an edit and a delete. I'm not sure how that would look though

Comment: Thank you. Let me ask you... Since there are 3 td cells, is it possible to allow the user to click the row instead of the td?

Comment: @user1709311 Actually, you want your entire `row` click for `edit` action, except that user click on `delete` button?

Comment: You know what Mojtaba? I can use what you've provided. I'll just add a class to each td. No big deal. :)

Comment: @user1709311 Yes, ofcourse. I've updated my answer again. Everything is possible with a browser and javascript, and ofcourse, jquery :)

Comment: lol.. Yes it is! I am trying to learn more JQuery. I really like what it can do too!

Comment: Thank you very much for all of your help Mojtaba!

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use ID for the remove. Just traverse up tree to row:

```
$("td.delete").click(function (){
  var $row = $(this).closest('tr');
  $.post('test.php',{id: $row.attr('id')}, function(){
    $row.remove();
  },'json');
});
```

Comment: Thank you. I get id not defined with this.